# While converting UTC date to local date giving wrong time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have UTC date `/Date(1512624687600)/`

I want to convert it into local time but its giving me `2017-12-07 09:31 PM` Indian Standard Time etc. I had tried different types to get solution (local time). Please find my code below:

```
$scope.UtcToLocal = function(utcTime){
var milli = parseInt(utcTime.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1')); 
alert(milli);

var fromDate = moment(utcTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A");
alert(fromDate);

var gmtDateTime = moment.utc(fromDate, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A");
alert(gmtDateTime);

var local = gmtDateTime.local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');
return local;
```

I am using Moment.js code to demonstrate the above codes.

Comment: What output are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

UTC date time always give universal time of your region. most probably it will give you 4 hours later or earlier time. If you want get local time, then you need to use DateTime.Now in case of asp.net mvc